# How to assign a generic enum in a constructor in java?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CustomEnum {
    //?? varName;
    public <E extends Enum<E>> CustomEnum(Class<E> enumClass) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enumClass.getEnumConstants()));
        //?? varName = enumClass;
    }
}

public enum Mode {
    SAMPLE_A,
    SAMPLE_B,
    SAMPLE_C,
    SAMPLE_D
}
```

and I can call it in this way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomEnum customEnum = new CustomEnum(Mode.class);
    }
```

code output

```
[SAMPLE_A, SAMPLE_B, SAMPLE_C, SAMPLE_D]
```

What I want to do is assign the value of `enumClass` to a variable and assign it in the constructor but I don't know which type the variable should be, I tried with multiple ways but I get compilation errors, is this possible?

if the above is not possible, how could I convert a generic type
`E[]` which is returned by `getEnumConstants()` to a `String[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the whole class generic, not just the constructor.

```
public class CustomEnum<E extends Enum<E>> {

    private E[] constants;

    public CustomEnum(Class<E> enumClass) {
        constants = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
    }

}
```